# cypher query is not returning the results when trying to use @QueryResult to map to POJO

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm running a cypher query using

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session#query(java.lang.Class<T>, java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>)
```

The Class is a POJO which I have annotated using **@QueryResult**

```
@QueryResult
public class Neo4jQueryResultClip {
    private String clipUuid;

    private String postTitle;

    private Date clipCreatedAt;
//getters and setters
}
```

My query cypher goes something like this

```
match (c:Clip) where (:User{uuid:{uuidParam}})-[:USER_FOLLOWS_USER]->(:User)-[:CLIP_BY_USER]->(c) OR (:User{uuid:{uuidParam}})-[:CLIP_BY_USER]->(c)match (c)<-[:CLIP_PRODUCT|:CLIP_INSPIRATION]-(post) optional match (c)<-[cp:CLIP_PRODUCT]-(post) return c.uuid as clipUuid,c.createdAt as clipCreatedAt,post.title as postTitle order by c.createdAt DESC
```

However the iterator of results returned is empty

If I run the same query using

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session#query(java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>)
```

I get proper results encapsulated in the

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.Result
```

object.

Is there something I am missing here?
I have verified that the class **Neo4jQueryResultClip** is getting scanned by neo4j spring configuration
I am using following versions
spring-data-neo4j (4.0.0.RELEASE) and neo4j-ogm library (1.1.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@QueryResult` used on in Spring Data Neo4j repositories (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult) so that's why it isn't mapped.

If you do this instead inside a repository

```
@Query("match (c:Clip) where (:User{uuid:{uuidParam}})-[:USER_FOLLOWS_USER]->(:User)-[:CLIP_BY_USER]->(c) OR (:User{uuid:{uuidParam}})-[:CLIP_BY_USER]->(c)match (c)<-[:CLIP_PRODUCT|:CLIP_INSPIRATION]-(post) optional match (c)<-[cp:CLIP_PRODUCT]-(post) return c.uuid as clipUuid,c.createdAt as clipCreatedAt,post.title as postTitle order by c.createdAt DESC")
Neo4jQueryResultClip getClip(...);
```

then it should work just fine.

Comment: if it possible to use it without a repository? like calling session.query, i believe under the hood the repository might be calling the same api.

Comment: No, the mapping to the QueryResult is additional in SDN.

Comment: another question, can I use a query to return multiple Node entities and some flags                                                                                                       @QueryResult
public class Neo4jQueryResultClipObjs {
    private Clip clip;
    private Product product;
    private User clippper;
    private Boolean hasClipped;
    private Boolean feedUserLikesClip;                                                                }

Comment: this would make the flow pretty simpler and not dependent on field names

Comment: currently If I change it, it returns me null for Node entity objects inside the QueryResult mapped class

Comment: This is available in neo4j-ogm 2.0.0-M01